# This function removes stray brackets from inbetween shortcodes. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

**How to clean up this code?**

Wordpress uses shortcodes in the form [shortcode] to add extended functionality to posts and pages.

What I am trying to do is to return a string with all of the 'stray' brackets, ones not being used by any of shortcodes, as html entities.

What I have to work with are these variables via WordPress:

$shortcode_tags: an array of all shortcodes as strings (without brackets)

and

get_shortcode_regex(): combines all registered shortcode tags into a single regular expression. (I am not using this in the code below)

```
function find_stray_brackets ($content) {
// this code repalces all occurences of every shortcode with special brackets.
// It then replaces remaining 'stray' brackets with the HTML character entitiy.

        global shortcode_tags;
        foreach($shortcode_tags as $k=>$item)
        {
            $pattern='/\[('.$k.'.*?(?=\]))\]/';
            $content=preg_replace($pattern,'*{*$1*}*',$content);
            $pattern='/\[\/('.$k.'.*?(?=\]))\]/';
            $content=preg_replace($pattern,'*{*/$1*}*',$content);
        }

        $content=str_replace('[','&#91;',$content);
        $content=str_replace(']','&#93;',$content);
        $content=str_replace('*{*','[',$content);
        $content=str_replace('*}*',']',$content);

    return($content);
}
```

The approach is to replace all of the brackets that surround shortcodes with special characters-> replace stray brackets with html entities -> re-insert original brackets

Comment: maybe http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask...

Comment: Thanks Tivie, posted on code review.